# How to find positive matches of regex in the directory and return needed exit code?

Tags: regex, bash

I need to return exit code 1 if my egrep condition counts > 1 match 
So I have a file: **test.txt** with next content:

```
{% url my_view %}
{% url my_view user_id %}
{% url 'my_view' %}
{% url 'my_view' user_id %}
{% url "my_view" user_id %}
{% url "my_view" %}
```

And I have next bash script with egrep inside:

```
#!/bin/bash
    if [ "$(grep -c "(% url+ )([0-9a-z_:]+)" test.txt)" -ge 1 ]; then
        echo true 
        exit 1
    else
        echo false 
        exit 0
    fi
```

So this line suppose to return true if my grep expression has more then 1 match:

`[ "$(grep -c "(% url+ )([0-9a-z_:]+)" test.txt)" -ge 1 ];`

But I always get false, nomatter what.

Here is the proof that regex is working:

https://regex101.com/r/zZ9vF5/8#python

So what do I need to change so that I can retrieve exit code 1 if my regex has more then one match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly stated "egrep condition", but there's no `egrep` nor `grep -E` in your script.

Are you sure you need the `+` after the `l`? Do you expect `urlllll` to appear in the input?

Also, `-ge` means `>=`, use `gt` to test for `>`.

Comment: I have another small question, how do I run this script for each file in the directory?

Comment: @Tachi: `for file in $dir/*; do ... done`, use `"$file"` instead of `test.txt`.

Comment: I have a directory with unkown number of subfolders and files in it, and I need to run it on each file I can find. Maybe it's a question for another topic?

Comment: @Tachi: It's always better to ask a new question as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arithmetic :

```
if (($(grep -c "(% url+ )([0-9a-z_:]+)" file) >= 1)); then ...
```