# How to run bash script on each file in the directory and its subdirectories?

Tags: bash

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    if [ $(egrep -c "(% url+ )([0-9a-z_:]+)" 'test.txt') -gt 2 ]; then
        echo true 
        exit 1
    else
        echo false 
        exit 0
    fi
```

And I was testing it on a `test.txt`, but how do I run it on each file in directory and it's subdirectories? If I just try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
    if [ $(egrep -c "(% url+ )([0-9a-z_:]+)" '~/Documents/somefolder/targetfolder/') -gt 2 ]; then
        echo true 
        exit 1
    else
        echo false 
        exit 0
    fi
```

It clearly doesn't work and gives me next output:

```
egrep: ~/Documents/somefolder/targetfolder/: No such file or directory
./run.sh: line 2: [: -gt: unary operator expected
false
```

So how can I run my script on each file in the directory, even if it's located in subdirectories?

Comment: What should the exit status be? 1 if any file has 2+ matches, or 1 if all files have 2+ matches? (Also, you might want to exit 0 with `echo true`, to match the convention that 0 means success, non-zero means failure.)

Comment: I need to return exit code 1 if anything matches the pattern. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612068/how-to-find-positive-matches-of-regex-in-the-directory-and-return-needed-exit-co 2+ matches is just a test value

Comment: Are you sure that `~/Documents/somefolder/targetfolder/` actually exists?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you what with `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec script.sh {} \;
```

The spaces, the trailing backslash and the semicolon are all important. This find command looks for all files at or below . and then executes `script.sh` on each of them passing it the current file upon which it is operating as an argument. For instance, the following command will give you a word-count of each file in a hierarchy by running the `wc` command on each file:

```
find . -type f -exec wc {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that `~` will not get expanded inside quotes.